# Como pegar dados depois de um 2 separadores de string em um select (SQL)?

Tags: sql

Tenho uma string onde armazeno dia, mês e ano, nenhum campo é obrigatório, e separo os campos por um pipe **|**.

Se o usuário colocou só o dia via ficar "25", se colocou o dia e o mês ou só o mês vai ficar respectivamente "25|12" ou "|12".

A mesma lógica para ano o que se pode concluir é que se tiver ano a string vai ter 2 pipes.

Eu precisava pegar o valor do ano, ou seja o valor depois do 2º pipe que inclusive pode ser vazio, caso o usuário tenha apagado. O usuário pode digitar 1 ou 2 caracteres para dia ou mês e até 3 caracteres para o ano, com isso não posso usar `substring` contando os caracteres.

Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Simplifique a coisa, crie um campo de data ou três campos para dia,mês e ano. Fora isto se quiser complicar  use as FUNCTIONS de STRING do respectivo BD (não informado) para manipular a string em questão.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função [RIGHT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms177532.aspx) que retorna o(s) ultimo(s) elemento(s) da string e fazer um case para verificar se seu caractere esta na ultima posição.

```
declare @teste table
(
  dha varchar(20)
)

insert into @teste values 
('25'),('25|'),('||'),('||16'),('||016'),('|02|016'),('|02|16'),('01||'),('01|02|'),('01|02|16'),('01|02|016')


select CHARINDEX('|', dha),  
case 
    when  (CHARINDEX('|', dha) = 0) or (RIGHT(dha, 2) = '||' or RIGHT(dha, 1) = '|') then ''
    else RIGHT(dha, 2)
end

from @teste
```